# Creating Spring Framework task programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I need to create task on the fly in my app. How can I do that? I can get scheduler with `@autowired` annotation, but scheduler takes `Runnable` objects. I need to give Spring objects, so that my tasks can use `@autowired` annotation too.

```
@Autowired private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to wrap your target object in a `Runnable`, and submit that:

```
private Target target;  // this is a Spring bean of some kind
@Autowired private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

public void scheduleSomething() {
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          target.doTheWork();
       }
    };
    taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, delay);
}
```

Comment: I cannot access target in that context. Eclipse says sytnax error.

Comment: @newbie: Yes, I was giving you the general idea, not working code.

Comment: problem sovled, I added implements Runnable to my task class (aka target)

Comment: @skaffman For some reason, the taskScheduler is not injected. Do you know if a TaskScheduler is created when EnableScheduling is set on the configuration class? Thanks!